# Which one is the correct to use "onto" or "Into" in this context?

Tags: vocabulary, american-english, british-english, learning

in the text:

"In a rosary, beads are threaded onto a string to attach the beads together."

which make more sence:

1 -threaded onto a string

2 - threaded into a string

Answer (score 2):

Definitely *onto*, since the string is inside the beads.

The only way you would use *into* is if you said that the beads were *made into* a rosary (used as the materials to make one).

Comment: I1m confused by the definition of "onto" that say if "action happen on a surface of an object" bu beads are put a string through it not on surface, get it?

Comment: String doesn't have much of a surface, but the beads go on the _outside_ of the string.

Answer (score 0):

"beads are threaded onto a string" (correct)

"beads are threaded into a string" (incorrect. The beads do not go inside the string)

"A string is threaded into [some] beads" (correct because it is the string that goes *inside* each bead)

Comment: So isn't the phrase: "beads are threaded onto a string..." wrong? I mean the "beads are threaded" part?

Comment: isn't only a thread that is capable of threading?

Comment: I suppose that you could say that the beads are threaded into (converted into) a string of beads. The problem is the verb "to thread". It depends which definition you use. Look at the different definitions of the verb here - *https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/thread*